# How can i display the json datas by it's ID's from the JSON file using angular js?

Tags: angularjs

```js
<!-- this is my JS -->

var fbResponse = angular.module("myApp", []);

fbResponse.controller("myController", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http)
  {    
   $http.get('js/data.json').success (function(data){
    $scope.fbData = data;
   }); 


  }]
);
<!-- This is my json data -->

{
  "data": [{
    "id": "10203027538760940",
    "name": "Ritesh Shrestha",
    "picture": {
      "data": {
        "is_silhouette": false,
<!-- continue -->
        "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/13423920_10208483094066413_1772738469682095118_n.jpg?oh=3790e0e413d27ac2873e874ff1739703&oe=57D257BD&__gda__=1472669236_44f83d9d0bc42388df27155b6d3193d9"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "id": "100000490421782",
    "name": "Nepal Ranjan Gautam",
    "picture": {
      "data": {
        "is_silhouette": false,
        "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/c0.0.50.50/p50x50/12734205_1374357905923877_8058586332399618941_n.jpg?oh=6cbc51645fc73f9d788bab2b69ef70a8&oe=57E026AD&__gda__=1473260380_81e02b279acde7ba238c3bee2b275126"
      }
    }
  }, {
    "id": "100002435031519",
    "name": "Chandra Shekhar Pandey",
    "picture": {
      "data": {
        "is_silhouette": false,
        "url": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/c8.0.50.50/p50x50/13494950_1030964580328033_9101157096437530113_n.jpg?oh=fd9ff64eb2c3e884905d0a09bf95935a&oe=57C97A13&__gda__=1474319842_88a9c5b94b7e934d086a03134d42d0fe"
      }
    }
  }],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUm1KVUl0TWk1RHpYQ1JSVVFBZAUY4ZA1p0Ul9pZAUItbktxUTNwWmVqQkZAETml5SF9iRkpkSkZAJbUlXalFOc0NvdXUZD",
      "after": "QVFIUnNic0R4T29BLUlZAaldXbi1SVHM4WUp0cFFxRkJib19paldhTHpxZADdXa1c1eVBIQnV5Wkd1YjZAwMmlQQmJxd0pDcWNMVmdHS2F5d2RTaWx4VmdhOEh3"
    }
  },
  "summary": {
    "total_count": 346
  }
}
<!-- End of json data -->
```

```html
<!-- This is my angular html format -->

                    <div ng-repeat="item in fbData" class="border">
      <div class="comment-display">
       <p class="comment-image"><img src="{{item.image}}" width="50"></p>
       <aside class="comment-name">
        <p class="name"> {{item.name }}</p>
        <p class="day"> {{item.time }}</p>
       </aside>
      </div>
      <p> {{item.description}}</p>
     </div>
```

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you are asking for. Do you want order the data in a specific way by the ID or do you just simply want to display the ID?

Comment: No John I want the data to be displayed by calling it's id from the json file. <p class="name"> {{item.name }}</p>   I have called the data like this without calling the ID. I want to extract all the information of an object with a single id.

Comment: where is the code for getting data by id? or where are you going to put it?

Comment: `ng-repeat="item in fbData | orderBy:'+id'"`

Comment: What is the format to display above JSON data in angularjs.

Comment: I don't think it is very clear what you mean when you say, "by calling it's id from the json file". Are you trying to display all of the data in the json? Or are you trying to just display a placeholder (id or name or something) that links to the rest of the data? Please explain more what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to display the json data in the browser by calling it's ID.